# Is it correct to use custom directives for templating in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I have a navigation bar and footer on every page in my AngularJS app. Would it be a good idea to put both of those into custom directives to be able to change them without updating every html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly a valid approach, and is much better than repeating yourself everywhere. If the navbar and footer don't rely on any $scope bindings, you can even just create templates and load them in using the `ng-include` directive.

An (arguably) better way would be to create nested views. The default router is a bit limited in that regard, but [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is very well suited for this. [These slides here](http://slides.com/timkindberg/ui-router#/) do a pretty good job explaining how ui-router can help.

The nested view approach would be to create a top-level application view that's made up of three named child views.

```
Container View
|
| - - NavBar View
|
| - - Main View
|
| - - Footer View
```

You can even expand on this later by introducing sidebar views and the like.